# How to use a VPN Client inside Azure VM and Keep Remote Desktop Connection available?

Tags: vpn, cisco-vpn

I have a virtual network in Azure using point-to-site connection. I connect to it using Azure VPN normally and access my VMs through remote desktop normally as well.

The problem is, I want to run a Cisco VPN Client inside one of these machines, but when i DO this and connect to VPN i lose my remote desktop connection and the machine cannot be detected anymore in my network.

Using other machines inside my virtual network i cannot ping the machine anymore, so i reboot it and when it gets back (without vpn connected inside) i can ping it again normally.

What i believe is that VPN is taking all my network adapter or overriding the other one in a way that my computer does not answer to its original ip address anymore.

Someone knows what can i do? Or maybe how can i connect my azure gateway to this vpn and let all my computers acessing it as well (sharing VPN connection)?

Answer (score 3):

Modify the properties of the VPN interface, under IPv4 Settings, to NOT use the remote gateway:

[image]

If this configuration is not allowed, the administrator of the remote network has disabled it (usually for security purposes, so that information is less likely to leak between networks).

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too. I don't have a "Use default gateway on remote network" checkbox to check. There is a solid workaround: use an alternate method to remote into the machine like GoToMyPC. It uses a different method of connecting, and in my case I was able to connect with it and then initiate the VPN connection without trouble.